# Hierarchy Id, find parent by child

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table with following structure

```
Id         P1              P2(HirarchyId) 
-----     ------           --------------
1          Name1           /1600/1601/
2          Name2           /1300/
```

The key of hirarchy id is foreign key of different table

```
Id         P2
----       ------
1600       p2Name1
1601       p2Name2
1300       p2Name3
```

I want to write a query which can give result based on Id's of P2 I pass.

Something Like this

```
select Id, P1 from TableP1 where P2 in (1600, 1300)
```

I know it is not possible but need some alternative to achieve this. Please let me know if it is possible or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TableP1.Id, TableP1.P1
  FROM TableP1
  JOIN TableP2 ON TableP1.P2.ToString() like '/'+TableP2.Id+'%'
              AND TableP2.Id in (1600, 1300)
```

Comment: Thanks it Works with slight change, Need to convert HirarchyId to string.    -- ON TableP1.P2.ToString() like '/'+TableP2.Id+'%' --